# Prove monotonicity of a sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, monotone-functions

$1)$
I have a sequence defined in terms of a recurring relationship. Namely, $$s_0=\sqrt{2},\;s_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}.$$
I could prove that it is bounded, but having difficulty in proving that it is monotonic so that I can apply Heine-Borel theorem to prove convergence. Can someone tell me how to do it?

$2)$
Also how to calculate the limit rigorously.
I calculated it using the fact that we can substitute both $s_n$ and $s_{n+1}$ with a supposed limit $l$. While it is intuitive that this approach works, I need a rigorous proof of how such an evaluation works without using concepts of continuity and differentiability as the book (baby Rudin) I am going through didn't reach there yet.

Comment: Yes. This answers the first part. Looking for the second part now.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2066393/266110) clearly answers your second question.

Comment: In this question, the limit is pushed inside the sqrt, and without assuming continuity of it, such an argument won't be valid, right?

Comment: No, you only need [$x_n \to l \implies \sqrt{x_n} \to \sqrt{l}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99345/show-that-if-x-n-to-x-then-sqrtx-n-to-sqrtx)

Comment: This makes sense. Should I mark it as a duplicate ?

Comment: I believe so. $\;\;$

Comment: If you don't want to use continuity than the main claim of the answer proposed by Sahiba Arora needs to be proven... But again, why should you make everything so complicated when continuity is there just for that?

Comment: That's right. But marked as duplicate because proving the limit of sqrt from first principle seems much easier than the general problem. So I am satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You claime to have proved the boundedness of the sequence.

MONOTONICITY:
Clearly, $s_1>s_0=\sqrt2.$
For $n\geq 1,$ et us compute
$$\begin{aligned}s_{n+1}-s_n&=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}-\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}\\\\&=\frac{\sqrt{s_n}-\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}{\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}}\\\\&=\frac{s_n-s_{n-1}}{\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{s_n}+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}\right)}_{>0}\underbrace{\left(\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}}\right)}_{>0}}\end{aligned}$$
**Edit**

> Therefore, if $s_{n}-s_{n-1}>0,$ then also $s_{n+1}-s_{n}>0.$ By induction, we conclude that
> $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N}:\;s_{n}>s_{n-1}.$$
> The sequence is increasing.

We have an increasing and bounded sequence, therefore it has a limit.

The way you used to find the limit is not intuitive, it is pretty legitimate:
**If the limit exists, then it satisfies the equation** $$l=\sqrt{2+\sqrt l}\tag{1}.$$
And we know already, that the limit exists.

The equation $(1)$ rewrites $$l^4-4l^2-l+4=(l-1)(l^3+l^2-3l-4)$$
With the use of Descartes'rule of signs we know that the cubic factor has exactly one positive root. With the use of numerical methods we find $\;l\approx 1.831177>\sqrt 2$

Comment: How do you prove the line written in bold? That's my second question actually.

Comment: It is an implication: If the limit exists and is a real number, then it is unique - therefore, the limite of $s_{n+1}$ equals that of $s_n.$

Comment: Till that line it is fine, how do you extend it to claim that limit of $s_{n+1}$ is same $\sqrt(2+ \sqrt( limit \space of \space s_n))$ without using continuity?

Comment: The proof of the monotonicity is wrong. It can't be that $s_{n+1}-s_n>s_n-s_{n-1}$ if not the sequence would diverge, being increasing. Indeed in the last equality you have to multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{s_{n+1}}-\sqrt{s_n}$ which can be (and actually is) less than $1$.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my childisch mistake, @ECL Edited.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is Rudin Exercise 3.3? To show that $\{s_n\}$ is monotonic, you can use induction. Indeed, for $n=1$ we have $s_1=\sqrt{2}$ and $s_2=\sqrt{2+\sqrt{\sqrt{2}}}$, so by the monotonicity of the square root function, $s_1<s_2$. Now for any $n\geq 1$, use some algebra to show that $s_n<s_{n+1}$. Then this establishes that
$$s_1<s_2<s_3<\cdots$$
and so $\{s_n\}$ is monotonic (in fact strictly increasing). Next, try to show that $s_n<2$ for all $n\geq 1$ (one possible approach is by contradiction: assume that there is a smallest integer $n\geq 2$ such that $s_n\geq 2$, and try to get a contradiction on the minimality of $n$).

At this point you have shown that $\{s_n\}$ is monotonic and bounded. Therefore, by theorem 3.14, $\{s_n\}$ converges. Finding the exact limit can be bit difficult -- it is the greater root of the equation $x^4-4x^2-x+4=0$, but that isn't easy to calculate.

Edit: the induction is as follows

$$s_{n+1}>s_n\iff \sqrt{2+\sqrt{s_n}}>s_n$$
$$\iff2+\sqrt{s_n}>s_n^2=2+\sqrt{s_{n-1}}$$
$$\iff \sqrt{s_n}>\sqrt{s_{n-1}}\impliedby s_n>s_{n-1}.$$

Comment: You have answered none of my questions. First you didn't say, how to use that bit of algebra, the thing I have asked for. Second i could calculate the limit, but I need to know why such an approach is rigorously valid. Thanks for answering anyway!

Comment: Hey, first of all, calm yourself down. You asked how one would show that the sequence is monotone, and since you are studying analysis, I didn't think you would need me to explicitly spell out the algebra step-by-step in order for you to figure it out. Secondly, don't lie to yourself -- you didn't calculate the roots of the polynomial equation by hand, so you couldn't just "calculate the limit".

Comment: Lol. I am calm only man. All I am saying is that your answer is not what I am looking for. If you find that algebra part this easy, would you mind spelling it out here. I am admitting in the question itself that I couldn't do it. And about the calculating part, I calculated it by putting it in a quartic solver as it has a closed form solution. The real roots are 1 and 1.8311772072083. As 1 can't be the limit as I have found a lower bound higher than 1 , the limit must be the second number. Remember, I never said, I calculated it by hand!

Comment: For sure man, it's perfectly fine if you want to use a calculator to approximate the limit. Nothing wrong with that. It just seems contradictory to me that you want to be able to prove things rigorously, yet you are also content with using a quartic solver to solve an equation only approximately.

Comment: I get your point. But it can be solved anyway, as it has a closed form solution just need to plug the coefficient into it. And also about the algebra bit, yeah man you were right! It was actually easy, so stupid of me to not see it. Now waiting for the answer to the second part.

Comment: Fyi, I added the induction. If you want to calculate what exactly the sequence converges to, that will be pretty difficult.

Comment: Thank you for the edit bit!

Answer (score 1):

First call $f$ the function
$$f:x\mapsto \sqrt{2+\sqrt{x}}\,.$$
$f$ is an increasing function because $g:y\mapsto\sqrt{y}$  and $h:y\mapsto 2+y$ are both increasing and $f = g\circ h\circ g$.

Now solving $f(x) = x$ you can find that there is a unique solution $x_\star$ and that this solution is positive. For $x=0$ you have that $f(0)>0$. So you can infer that $f(x)>x$ for all $x<x_\star$ and $f(x)<x$ for all $x>x_\star$. (To prove this rigorously the easiest way is to use continuity and the fact that the two graphs can cross just once. If you don't want to use this property you can solve explicitly like in ilovebulbasaur's answer.)

For all $s_n<x_\star$ you have $s_{n+1} = f(s_n)>s_n$. By induction you easily show that if $s_0<x_\star$ than all $s_n<x_\star$. This proves that the sequence is monotonic (increasing) if $s_0<x_\star$.

Now if you have find already $x_\star$ you will see that $\sqrt{2}<x_\star$. So the monotonicity is proven.

With an analog argument you prove that the sequence would be decreasing if $s_0<x_\star$.

To prove the existence of the limit you can use that the sequence is bounded and so must have a subsequence which is convergent (Bolzano-Weierstrass). Then since it is monotonic the whole sequence converge. Then it must converge to $x_\star$ because it is the only fixed point.

Comment: The fix point approach really makes sense, but without leaving out the continuity bit, it is a bit hard to make it rigorous. And again to argue that for a no. to be limit, it must be a fixed point, I am finding it a bit hard to do without continuity.

Comment: Increasing generating function does not necessarilly give an increasing sequence (in our case is the sequence increasing, which is a coincidence). Therefore, your first step is wrong.

Comment: I'm not saying that the increasing generating function gives an increasing sequence. I'm saying that the monotonicity of the generating function can be used to prove that for any $x< x_\star$ you have $f(x)>x$ and it is this last property which makes the sequence to be increasing.

Comment: To prove that the fixed point is the limit again the best way is to use continuity. If you want to avoid it you have to use some inequality showing that if the limit is $l$ and $|x_\star -l|>\epsilon$ then $f(x)-x>\delta_\epsilon>0$ for all $x<l$. You can for sure find some bound of this kind and then you get a contradiction since you cant converge at $l$. You can try to make it rigorous but I would say it's a bit a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

$x$ is increasing$\implies\sqrt x$ is increasing $\implies2+\sqrt x$ is increasing$\implies\sqrt{2+\sqrt x}$ is increasing.

Now if the sequence converges, it converges to a solution of

$$s=\sqrt{2+\sqrt s}$$ which is a root of

$$(s^2-2)^2-s$$ and exceeds $\sqrt2$.

By inspection $s=1$ is a solution and after long division $$s^3+s^2-3s-4=0$$ remains. Then by the substitution

$$s:=\frac{2\sqrt{10}t-1}3$$ the equation becomes

$$4t^3-3t=\frac{79\sqrt{10}}{200}.$$

Now setting

$$t=\cosh(u),$$

$$\cosh(3u)=\frac{79\sqrt{10}}{200},
\\ t=\cosh\left(\dfrac13\text{arcosh}\left(\dfrac{79\sqrt{10}}{200}\right)\right),
\\s=\frac{2\sqrt{10}\cosh\left(\dfrac13\text{arcosh}\left(\dfrac{79\sqrt{10}}{200}\right)\right)-1}3.$$

Comment: Many thanks for the downvote.